# Creating an array column within my model definition

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I want to create a table in my SQLAlchemy Pyramid app that stores a multidimensional array of values. I'm using PostgreSQL and I know that it has an array type. I'm just not quite sure of how to define the table in my `models.py`. Maybe something like:

```
class MyTable:
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text_array = Column([Unicode])

    def __init__(self, text_array):
        self.text_array = text_array
```

Comment: If it's variable length and depth, prefer json. It'll be more straightforward to serialize and unserialize. And there's a json type which is useful in 9.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [to the SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY), you use the dialect-specific ARRAY type. Modifying your example leads to:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

class MyTable:
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text_array = Column(ARRAY(Unicode))

    def __init__(self, text_array):
        self.text_array = text_array
```

See the docs for multi-dimensional arrays (simply add the "dimensions" keyword argument to the ARRAY constructor).